# Eeeek! Skeet Bot is borked :(

Tags: bug, blog, robots

The [Thanks a Million, Jon Skeet!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/01/15/thanks-million-jon-skeet/) blog post contains what appears to be a Skeet Bot:

> [image]

However, clicking the "Ask Skeet Bot" button does... nothing. Closer inspection show that the [API used by the bot](https://skeetbot-webapp.azurewebsites.net/api/skeet-bot) is down.

Can the API please be brought back to life, or if not maybe better remove the part from the blog?

Comment: Wait, Jon Skeet is a robot? This answers *so much*!

Comment: Its answers were terrible, maybe it has been banned!

Comment: Do you know if this is still working? Tried to use access it at this address but no luck `skeetbot-webapp.azurewebsites.net/api/skeet-bot` (link found [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/01/15/thanks-million-jon-skeet))

Comment: @stevec not sure what you mean by "still working"? The whole point of this bug report is to report that it's not working. (And if you meant to ask if it's still **not** working, then the answer is yes, it's still the same as it was almost two years ago. :(

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask yea that's what I meant. I wasn't sure if I was accessing it correctly hence the caution in my wording (the url looks weird, starting with two forward slashes (did they forget the `http:` ?). My guess is someone pulled the app together as a fun project and it wasn't worth someone's effort to maintain, but that's purely conjecture

Comment: @steve the URL starting with two slashes is fine, it just means "use same protocol as current page", meaning if the page is http:// then the link "starts" with http:// as well, and if https:// then same is the link. Anyway, the server used to host the website running Skeet Bot (on Azure Network) was taken down, so I've asked to bring it back up, if possible.